# Use the shell method to find the volume of the solid that results when the region bounded by $y^2=8x$ and x=2 is revolved around the line x =4

Tags: calculus

my attempt: $2\pi \int_2^4 (4-x)(2 \sqrt {8x}) dx$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The limits are wrong.

Comment: the limits should be from x = 0 to 2?

Comment: Yes, those are the right limits. A picture does it.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture. We are taking a thin strip of width "$dx$" going from $x$ to $x+dx$, and rotating it about the line $x=4$. We get a cylindrical shell, with the radius of the cylinder equal to $4-x$, and the height of the cylinder equal to $2y$, that is, $2\sqrt{8x}$.

"Add up" (integrate) from the beginning of the region we are rotating  to the end, that is, from $x=0$ to $x=2$.